# why can't I use two indexes in a row?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use this code. But, for some reason I get an error that I do not fit into the range. It's just that several elements can come from the server, so I can't use hardcode and specify values like 1,2 and so on...

Here is the error I am getting -
***RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1***

And here is my code -

```
child: Text(' name - ${catalogDrawer[index].one[index].name}'),
```

of course it's wrapped in ListView.builder
***Essence of the question***. How can I use an index multiple times?

Comment: could you add the result of print('catalogDrawer[index] = ${catalogDrawer[index]}')?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to use `catalogDrawer[index].one[0].name`? Or can `one` have multiple elements?

Comment: Can you show the data, which you are trying to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said the only valid value for `one` is `0`, and your listView items is base on `catalogDrawer's length`. So you can't  use `catalogDrawer's index` on `one's items`. you either can use an other listView and use that index to show one's items or if you sure it only have one value use `catalogDrawer[index].one.first.name`.